# how to redirect to view in jquery ajax call using spring mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

Now my ajax call:

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: contextPath +"/action",
                cache:false,
                dataType: 'text',
                data: {Id:Id},
                success: function(Result){
                    alert("in success ***");
                    dialog.dialog("close");
                    window.location.href = Result;

                } ,
                error: function(Result){
                    alert("in error");
                    }
                });
```

My Controller code:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/action", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
  public @ResponseBody ModelAndView getApplyTemplatePage(@RequestParam("Id")int cId){
      System.out.println("In apply template controller");
      System.out.println("the value of id "+cId+" hostname"+hostName+"templateName"+tempName);

      return new ModelAndView("applyTemplate");
  }
```

Now i want to redirect to **applyTemplate.jsp page**.
My Requirement is using by ajax call how to redirect to another **jsp page** ?

Comment: You can not?for that you need to write another controller method and return to view from that method.

Comment: Your concept make no sense, ajax is used for doing something without loading the entire page. but you need to load the page finally. Why don't you directly let the controller to redirect? Since you are doing nothing inside success (except alert and redirect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a ResponseEntity with location header back in spring and redirect accordingly.

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getApplyTemplatePage(@RequestParam("Id") int cId, UriComponentsBuilder b) {
        UriComponents uriComponents = b.path("/applyTemplate.jsp").build();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(uriComponents.toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

and in the ajax call, you can get the location header and redirect accordingly.

```
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
      window.location = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
    }
```

Comment: I am using jquery load method for my requirement.

Comment: I have the same question. I thought that I have to send HttpStatus 302 or 303. Why do you send 200 ?

Comment: hello. how do you resolve... of course taken into consideration the   @Vinoth Krishnan's answer...